# Call custom function in function.php using woocommerce wordpress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to call a custom function in function.php on POST submit button in wordpress. 
Bellow you can see if statement when i  remove it function call work's perfectly but with if statement it's not work when I am post i am reached in if statement but not able to call the function.

```
if (isset($_POST['addcustomcarts']))

    {
        echo("if");
    add_filter('woocommerce_before_cart', 'customcart');
    //global $woocommerce;

    function customcart() {
    global $woocommerce;
    $my_post = array(
      'post_title'    => 'My post',
      'post_content'  => 'This is my post.',
      'post_status'   => 'publish',
      'post_author'   => 1,
      'post_type'     =>'product'
    );
    echo"sdafsdf";
    // Insert the post into the database
     $product_ID=wp_insert_post( $my_post );

     add_post_meta($product_ID, '_regular_price', 100, $unique);
     add_post_meta($product_ID, '_price', 100, $unique);
      add_post_meta($product_ID, '_stock_status', 'instock', $unique);



    $woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart( $product_ID, $quantity=1 );


    //exit;
    //header("Location: http://www.mydomain.com");exit();
    wp_redirect(".home_url('cart').");
    //wp_redirect(home_url());

    //global $wpdb;
    //$wpdb->query
    //exit;
    //exit;
    }

    }
```

Comment: Try moving the `customcart()` frunction definition out of the `if` block, and see what happens.

Comment: it works out of if block but i want to call function on an one event that's why i need if block. @geomagas

Comment: It makes no difference, does it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solve the issue use `add_action('init', 'customcart');` instead of `add_filter('woocommerce_before_cart', 'customcart');`

```
add_action('init', 'customcart');

function customcart() {

  if (isset($_POST["addcustomcarts"])) {

    global $woocommerce;

    $my_post = array(
      'post_title'    => 'My post',
      'post_content'  => 'This is my post.',
      'post_status'   => 'publish',
      'post_author'   => 1,
      'post_type'     =>'product'
    );

    // Insert the post into the database
    $product_ID = wp_insert_post( $my_post );

    if ( $product_ID ){
      add_post_meta($product_ID, '_regular_price', 100 );
      add_post_meta($product_ID, '_price', 100 );
      add_post_meta($product_ID, '_stock_status', 'instock' );

      //Getting error on this line.
      $woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart( $product_ID, $quantity=1 );

      exit( wp_redirect( get_permalink( woocommerce_get_page_id( 'cart' ) ) ) );

    }

  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the whole function from the if statement and only call the action. Like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['addcustomcarts']))

    {
        echo("if");
    add_filter('woocommerce_before_cart', 'customcart');
    //global $woocommerce;


    }


function customcart() {
    global $woocommerce;
    $my_post = array(
      'post_title'    => 'My post',
      'post_content'  => 'This is my post.',
      'post_status'   => 'publish',
      'post_author'   => 1,
      'post_type'     =>'product'
    );
    echo"sdafsdf";
    // Insert the post into the database
     $product_ID=wp_insert_post( $my_post );

     add_post_meta($product_ID, '_regular_price', 100, $unique);
     add_post_meta($product_ID, '_price', 100, $unique);
      add_post_meta($product_ID, '_stock_status', 'instock', $unique);



    $woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart( $product_ID, $quantity=1 );


    //exit;
    //header("Location: http://www.mydomain.com");exit();
    wp_redirect(".home_url('cart').");
    //wp_redirect(home_url());

    //global $wpdb;
    //$wpdb->query
    //exit;
    //exit;
    }
```